# Relevant Tabpage show when click the button in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I insert tab-control in my windows application.It has 4 tab-pages.I wanted to show only relevant tab-page when I click the relevant button..my code as follows

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPage1);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPage2);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPage3);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPage4);
        this.tabPage1.Hide();
        this.tabPage2.Hide();
        this.tabPage3.Hide();
        this.tabPage4.Hide();

    }
```

first every tab-page removed when form load

Here is the code for button click and I coded for 4 buttons...

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

 tabControl1.TabPages.Insert(0, tabPage1);
            this.tabPage1.Show();
            tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPage2);
            tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPage3);
            tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPage4);
            this.tabPage2.Hide();
            this.tabPage3.Hide();
            this.tabPage4.Hide();
}
```

I again used  ....

```
tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPage2);
            tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPage3);
            tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPage4);
            this.tabPage2.Hide();
            this.tabPage3.Hide();
            this.tabPage4.Hide();
```

these code. if  another tabpage is opened  when I click the button it should be remove and show relevant tabpage.Its working.

**My problem is..** **if I click the same button again and again same tabpages adding continuously**
**Can anyone give me a solution for it..**

Comment: After the form loads there are no tabs in the tab control. I doubt your code works at all. Hiding and showing should be enough.

Comment: It's working.When form is loading i want hide every tabpages.that's why i coded like that

Comment: But you are removing the tabs! That's different from hiding. And you're not showing code that readds them.

Comment: I used for tab-page hide its must be a tab-page remove.I used wrong word for describe my question.I accepted it.I'll edit it again.

Comment: If you click the same button multiple times then of course you're going to see the same tab page added multiple times. Your method for the button click is specifically adding the tab page. So if it gets clicked it will be added for every click. Only show or hide tab pages, no need to remove and add them.

Comment: Why are you calling both Remove and Hide? Sorry, it doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 0):

I founded a one way...In button click I modify like this.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPage1);
        if (tabControl1.TabPages.Count <= 1)
        {
            tabControl1.TabPages.Insert(0, tabPage1);
            this.tabPage1.Show();
            tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPage2);
            tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPage3);
            tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPage4);
            this.tabPage2.Hide();
            this.tabPage3.Hide();
            this.tabPage4.Hide();
        }
    }
```

first code is  `tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPage1)`.Then if tab-page is open It removed.If statement responsible for when button click relevant tab page is opened.then always show only one tab-page for button click moment